# Implementing FastApi-cache in a Django python project with docker

Tags: python, django, redis, fastapi

Currently trying to cache some expensive database queries in a Django project.

This is the code as it currently exists, Im having trouble verifying whats going wrong.  Currently getting an error that reads

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. -2.
```

So after some searching it appears im missing a 'redis-server', but after adding it to requirements.py am met with this error:

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for redis-server==5.0.7`

Ive also tried the other version i see listed, 6.0rc2, with no success

below is the full code im trying to run up:

```
import logging

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi_cache import FastAPICache
from fastapi_cache.backends.redis import RedisBackend
from fastapi_cache.decorator import cache
from redis import asyncio as aioredis


LOGGER = get_logger_with_context(logging.getLogger(__name__))



@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup() -> None:
    redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://redis", encoding="utf8", decode_responses=True, db=1)
    FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix="api-cache")
    LOGGER.info("API has started.")


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown() -> None:
    LOGGER.info("API has shutdown.")


@app.get("/health", include_in_schema=False)
def healthcheck() -> dict:
    """Lightweight healthcheck."""
    return {"status": "OK"}

@router.get(
    "/companies/attributes",
    summary="Retrieve company attributes, including leadership attributes, perks and benefits, and industry",
    response_model=CompanyAttributesOut,
    status_code=200,
)
@cache(expire=60, coder=JsonCoder)
def get_company_attributes() -> CompanyAttributesOut:
    """Retrieve the company attributes."""
    with async_safe():
        return CompanyAttributesOut.from_database_model()
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `FastApi-Cache` in a Django application, since it was made for and depends on (as you've discovered) FastAPI (a different web framework)? Also, redis is an external server and not part of your Python project (i.e. it's not a module you can install). You might want to look at using cachetools instead, which is a general caching / memoizing library for Python: https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - or configure caching in your http delivery path (using nginx, varnish or a similar tool).

Comment: its overall a django project, but we use the fastapi to house a large api application inside the app, so I thought fastapi-cache would be the way to go